# Javascript variable holds previous values

Tags: javascript, html

```
    function myFunction() {

        var words = ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow"];

        var random;
        var getRandomWord = function () {
            random = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);

            return words[random];
        };


        var word = getRandomWord();
        document.getElementById(word).style.backgroundColor = word;
        var element = document.getElementById(word);

        setTimeout(function () { document.getElementById(word).style.backgroundColor = "white" }, 500);

        element.onclick = function () {

            alert('hh');
        }
```

Each time I execute this function it should generate a random word which is ids of elements. But word holds previously generated random values too.

Here is [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/urgzs2fv/)

Comment: how do you run it multiple times??

Comment: <button class="button" onclick="myFunction()">play</button> by clicking

Comment: It's not clear what your actual problem is. What is going wrong from how you expect it to behave?

Comment: On clicking play button twice it shows color of two elements and increases on clicking multiple times. I expect it to show one element only.

Comment: well your code does not remove the last one so seems to be working as designed.

Comment: how do I remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that issue that your code generates the previous color because of the variable word holds previously generated random values when I tried your code in code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-leaf-ydxi4?fontsize=14

I find everything correct, the word show the same color twice sometimes because you are using Math.random, which maybe generate two similar number that returns the same Integer when using Math.floor, something like

```
Math.floor(0.954322992037227 * 4)
```

will result

```
3
```

and

```
Math.floor(0.9053765386684278 * 4)
```

will result

```
3
```

may you try to solve it like that without using Math.random : 
https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-rhodes-n58om?fontsize=14

**Update**: I misunderstood the problem, as Mentalist mentioned later in the comments:

> Press the play button twice (or until two different colours). I want it to alert hh only when you click on the recently generated colour, but it alerts on previous coloured rectangle too

the problem solved by reassigning a default onclick value for the elements,
this code will do the trick:

```
  let elements = document.getElementsByClassName("rectAngle");
  for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
   elements[i].onclick = function() {};
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort but you misunderstood my problem. I have attached the fiddle in the question. Press the play button twice (or until two different colours). I want it to alert hh only when you click on the recently generated colour, but it alerts on previous coloured rectangle too.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand you, try that https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-nobel-km7r3?fontsize=14

Comment: Wow! Thanks, Kamal it worked. Please post it as the answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: always welcome my friend, really glad that your issue solved, I edited the answer you can accept it now.

Answer (score 0):

You can put this before you set the color to clear any previous colors.

```
for(x=0; x<words.length; x++) {
    document.getElementById(words[x]).style.backgroundColor = "white" 
};
```

Edit:

ok, so you need to clear your onclick event when the colour changes to white.

Change the `element.onclick` to:

```
element.addEventListener('click', doAlert);
```

Put a new function, outside myFunction:

```
function doAlert() {
    alert('hh');
}
```

Change your setTimeout to:

```
setTimeout(function () { 
    document.getElementById(word).style.backgroundColor = "white";
    document.getElementById(word).removeEventListener('click', doAlert);
    }, 2000);
```

I've changed the timeout to 2 seconds, to make it easier to test.

And change the for loop that sets them to white:

```
for(x=0; x<words.length; x++) {
    document.getElementById(words[x]).style.backgroundColor = "white" 
    document.getElementById(words[x]).removeEventListener('click', doAlert);
};
```

This now makes sure they get cleared when the timer runs out, or they click to display a new box.

Comment: This just removes colour but previous values are still present.

Comment: @Mentalist I've just tried your JSFiddle, and it works fine. I alerted the word variable and it never contains more than 1 colour value. It does however show 2 coloured boxes at the same time, which my code above fixes.

Comment: your code makes the colour white but when you click on that white box it alerts. I want just one box coloured at a time.

Comment: @Mentalist see my edit.  The code is quite messy, and you should really declare `element` after you retrieve the random word, and use it in place of `document.getElementById(word)`